# Django template two ifequal in chain

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

My problem is in the last template with **ifequal** chain.
In the last template I have to select from model Contract acording to two parameters identified from privious two templates. I think that something is wrong in code sintax of the ifequal chain. Each **ifequal** separatly are also does not work. I feel myself like inside a wall.

1.template: valoare_list.html

```
 {% for valoare in valoares %}
      <a href="{% url 'valoare_detail' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare %}">
           Contracte de valoare {{ valoare.tip_valoare }}
      </a><br>
 {% endfor %}
```

2. template: valoare_detail.html

```
 {% for tip in tips %}
       <a href="{% url 'contract_list' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare tip=tip.tip_contract %}">
           Tip Contracte de {{ tip.tip_contract }}
       </a><br>
 {% endfor %}
```

3. template: contract_list.html

   ```
   {{ valoare.tip_valoare }} <br> 
   {{ tip.tip_contract }} <br> <br>

   {% for contract in contracts %}
       {% ifequal contract.valoare valoare.tip_valoare %}
           {% ifequal contract.tip tip.tip_contract %}
                {{ contract }} <br>
           {% endifequal %}
       {% endifequal %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

models.py

```
 from django.db import models


 class Valoare(models.Model):
     VALOARE_CHOICES = (
          ("MICA","mica"),
          ("MARE","mare"),
     )
     tip_valoare = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=VALOARE_CHOICES, default="MICI", verbose_name='valoarea contractului')
     file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='contracte/templates/contracte/img/', verbose_name='img path')

     def __str__(self):
          return self.tip_valoare


  class Tip(models.Model):
      TIP_CHOICES = (
          ("BUNURI","bunuri"),
          ("SERVICII","servicii"),
          ("LUCRARI","lucrari"),
      )
      tip_contract = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TIP_CHOICES, default="BUNURI", verbose_name='tipul contractului')
      file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='contracte/templates/contracte/img/', verbose_name='img path')

    def __str__(self):
         return self.tip_contract


 class Contract(models.Model):
     valoare = models.ForeignKey('Valoare')
     tip = models.ForeignKey('Tip')
     data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
     file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='pdf/', verbose_name='contract file name')

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.data)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ["data"]
```

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
 from .models import Valoare, Tip, Contract


 def valoare_list(request):
     valoares = Valoare.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'contracte/valoare_list.html', {'valoares': valoares})


 def valoare_detail(request, valoare):
     valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, tip_valoare=valoare)
     tips = Tip.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'contracte/valoare_detail.html', { 'valoare': valoare, 'tips':tips })


 def contract_list(request, valoare, tip):
     valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, tip_valoare=valoare)
     tip = get_object_or_404(Tip, tip_contract=tip)
     contracts = Contract.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'contracte/contract_list.html', {'valoare': valoare, 'tip': tip, 'contracts':contracts})
```

urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from . import views


 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.valoare_list, name='valoare_list'),
     url(r'^valoare/(?P<valoare>[A-Z]{4})/$', views.valoare_detail, name='valoare_detail'),
     url(r'^valoare/(?P<valoare>[A-Z]{4})/(?P<tip>[A-Z]+)/$', views.contract_list, name='contract_list'),
 ]
```

I can not understand - Why **ifequal** is not working in template nr.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last selection I manage in the

views.py

```
 def contract_list(request, valoare, tip):
     valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, tip_valoare=valoare)
     tip = get_object_or_404(Tip, tip_contract=tip)
     finals = Contract.objects.filter(valoare__tip_valoare=valoare, tip__tip_contract=tip)
     return render(request, 'contracte/contract_list.html', {'valoare': valoare, 'tip': tip, 'finals':finals})
```

contract_list.html - the thierd template is:

```
 {% for final in finals %}
         {{ final }}<br>
 {% endfor %}
```

in **finals** variable I put "double parameter" filter and the QUERY worked perfect. I am a starter and I feel myself that I opened the world.